# Unhandled exception Error in C++ Recursion

Tags: c++, c++11

so i have this function which use recursion to find the longest sequence of numbers. but every time i run it, i get this error message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x002871D9 in increasingSeq.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0x01060EC0.

```
int seqeter(int grid, int startPos,  int seq)
{
    Sequence maxseq;
    maxseq.size = 0;
    for (int rows=0;rows<MAXROWS;rows++)
    {
        for(int cols=0;cols<MAXCOLS;cols++)
        {

            if (grid[startPos.x][startPos.y] < grid[startPos.x+rows][startPos.y+cols])

            {
                return seq;
            }

            else 
            {
                maxseq.list[maxseq.size] = grid[startPos.x][startPos.y];
                maxseq.size ++;
             return generateSeq(grid, startPos, seq);
            }

        }
    }

    return maxseq;
}
```

Comment: This little code will run to infinity and beyond... the same start position is passed over and over

Comment: ***Why*** is this a recursive function?

Comment: No, this is not a recursive function.

Answer (score 4):

You're not advancing from your `startPos` - the recursion never stops and you quickly crash the stack.

Comment: SO isn't a homework/whatever solving mechanism. Your specific problem has been pointed out. If you need help with algorithm, ask an appropriate question and describe http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: the above code is what i came up with. but im getting an error. which you say its because im not advancing from my startpos. but can you explain how to advance from my startpos?

Comment: You need to change the `startPos` to reflect your next step before you invoke the recursive call (`generateSeq(grid, startPos, seq)`).

Comment: Add 1 to `startPos.x` or `startPos.y` (I'm not sure which -- I don't really understand what your code is supposed to be doing).

Comment: One way to learn what is actually going on, is to run this code under a debugger.